# Can I change the difficulty during the game and still get the appropriate achievement?

Tags: achievements, darksiders-2

If I play, for example, on normal and run into a tough spot, change the difficulty to easy, get past the the part I had trouble with then change back to normal - will I still get the appropriate achievements or not?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot change difficulty mid-game and still get the higher difficulty's trophy.

Difficulty trophies do stack, however. So for example, you will get the Normal and Easy trophies for finishing on Apocalyptic